# New to keras neural network and k-fold cross validation

Tags: neural-network, keras, cross-validation, python-3.x

I'm new to learning neural networks and I found an example online to test accuracy with k-fold cross validation.

The example is for binary data but I want to test MAE or RMSE (I guess?) for my regression prediction. I'm a bit lost now on how I can test it because currently the accuracy is mostly 0.00%, sometimes 1.94%, I assume because my data is not binary.

Here is my code:

```
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load pima indians dataset
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
# define 10-fold cross validation test harness
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=12, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Fit the model
    model.fit(X.iloc[train], Y.iloc[train], epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
    # evaluate the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X.iloc[test], Y.iloc[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores), numpy.std(cvscores)))
```

So my question is: how do I test MAE for regression data with k-fold cross validation?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should use accuracy as a metric, you can test your MAE (Mean Absolute Error) by changing the metric in the compiling line.

```
model.compile(..., metrics=['mae'])
```

If you want to use RMSE you can define it yourself (it's not built-in in keras):

```
from keras import backend
 
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[rmse])
```

Good luck :)